# Magento Editor showing Denied Message in image

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4

I am using magento version 1.9.2.4 and trying to insert image using editor. when press the add/insert image from editor a popup shows me "Denied" Message instead of image uploading option. please check the below screen.
[image]

Comment: It simply means that your apache user does not have correct permissions for folders and files. Please correct server permissions and try again.

Comment: but why it is working with insert image button without the editor. means when we hide the editor.

Comment: add error from browser here

Comment: Please check browser's console whether there is any js error while trying to upload image or not?

Comment: getting this error ""NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - /js/tiny_mce/plugins/advimage/image.htm""

Answer (score 0):

There may be some problem with permission to the file.

so login through FTP/cpanel and provide 777 permission to file having path

/js/tiny_mce/plugins/advimage/image.htm